# Dynamic Sizing in CollectionView based on TextView

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I'm trying to implement the dynamic cell sizing based on TextView content in collection view. I have tried by using the `estimatedSize` in collection view
`collectionView.estimatedSize = CGSize(width: 1, height: 1)` but its not giving the smooth scrolling and takes more time to render the data's. If I use `UILabel` instead of `UITextView` the scrolling is smooth. I have referred lot of blogs but didn't get the proper solution.

Can anyone refer me a proper solution. Thanks in advance.

Note: If anyone need extra information, ask in comment section.

Comment: This might help you.. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45204283/collectionview-dynamic-height-with-swift-3-in-ios

Comment: do you want to improve collectionView loading speed or want to boost smooth scrolling?

Comment: I like to implement the dynamic sizing of cells using flowlayout which should be smooth for scrolling.

Comment: ok just have a look here.. https://medium.com/capital-one-developers/boost-smooth-scrolling-with-ios-10-pre-fetching-api-818c25cd9c5d

Comment: just check my library you will get your answer https://github.com/sagarshirbhate/DynamicHeightForCollectionView

Comment: Did you ever find a working solution? I’m trying to do the same thing.